# Recovering LINE account chat history after a delete and reinstall

Tags: titanium-backup, line

I deleted and reinstalled my LINE messaging app since it kept notifying me to do so the past few days (which I found odd because it was on the latest version). I'm guessing it might have had something to do with me playing around with Lucky Patcher to install a modded version of Google Playstore, which ultimately failed so I had to flash GAPPS to get the playstore back after LP uninstalled it.

Anyways, I backed up my LINE app using Titanium Backup before deleting and reinstalling. After the reinstall, I opened LINE, logged in, and saw that all my chat history has been deleted so I ran TB to restore the data (restore app + data didn't let me install LINE so I installed it through the PlayStore and just restored the data using TB).

However, when I opened LINE again, I saw everything restored briefly until I got notified that my account is being used on another device and I was forced to delete everything.

I looked through the questions and answers in StackExchange, Reddit, and XDA but most of their problems involved transferring their LINE app to a different phone, or a different ROM (but the same phone). All I did was to **delete and reinstall** so my android id should not have changed so it doesn't make sense why LINE is giving me that notice.

Does anyone have ideas on how to fix this?

Phone: OnePlus 6, Android 9, rooted.

Thanks!